# Fonts look pixelated in some applications

Tags: kde, fonts, qt, kde5, qtcreator

I use KDE, I have a HiDPI display, so I made changes to `~/.Xresources` to change the system DPI. After that, the fonts in some applications began to look pixelated.
[image]
[image]
[image]

In QtCreator, with `QT_SCALE_FACTOR=1.2`, icons become pixelated.

[image]

How to fix this problem?

My `~/.Xresources`:

```
Xft.dpi:        120
Xft.antialias:  true
Xft.rgba:       rgb
Xft.hinting:    true
Xft.hintstyle:  hintslight
```

Output of `xrdb -q`:

```
Xft.antialias:  1
Xft.dpi:        120
Xft.hinting:    -1
Xft.hintstyle:  hintslight
Xft.rgba:       none
```

**UPD:** My system:

Operating System: Arch Linux 

KDE Plasma Version: 5.16.3

KDE Frameworks Version: 5.60.0

Qt Version: 5.13.0

Kernel Version: 5.2.1-arch1-1-ARCH

Comment: I changed DPI to more comfortable 130, and fonts became beautiful...